# How do you say, “I got swept up by the ocean,” in Korean?

Tags: translation

As the title says, how do you say “I got swept up by the ocean” in Korean?

Comment: what have you tried to translate this?

Answer (score 0):

- "바다에 휩쓸려 갔다"
- "I got swept up by the ocean"